# Oracle: Poor performance on smaller result sets?

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I am running into a very strange bit of behavior with a query in Oracle The query itself is enormous and quite complex...but is basically the same every time I run it. However, it seems to execute more slowly when returning a smaller result-set. The best example I can give is that if I set this filter on it,

```
and mgz_query.IsQueryStatus(10001,lqo.query_id)>0
```

which returns 960 of 12,429 records, I see an execution time of about 1.9 seconds. However, if I change the filter to

```
and mgz_query.IsQueryStatus(10005,lqo.query_id)>0
```

which returns 65 of 12,429 records, I see an execution time of about 6.8 seconds. When digging a bit deeper, I found that it seems the smaller result set was performing considerably more buffer gets than the larger result set. This seems completely counter-intuitive to me.

The query this is being run against is roughly 8000 characters long (Unless someone wants it, I'm not going to clutter this post with the entire query), includes 4 'Union All' statements, but otherwise filters primarily on indexes and is pretty efficient, apart from its massive size.

The filter in use is executed via the below function.

```
Function IsQueryStatus(Pni_QueryStateId        in number,
                         Pni_Query_Id       in number) return pls_integer as
    vn_count pls_integer;
  Begin
    select count(1)
      into vn_count
     from m_query mq
    where mq.id = Pni_Query_Id
      and mq.state_id = Pni_QueryStateId;

    return vn_count;
  End;
```

Any ideas as to what may be causing the smaller result set to perform so much worse than the large result set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are facing a situation where determining that something is *not* in the set takes a lot longer than determining if it *is* in the set.  This can occur quite often.  For instance, if there is an index on `m_query(id)`, then consider how the `where` clause might be executed:

(1) The value `Pni_Query_Id` is looked up in the index.  There is no match. Query is done with a value of `0`.

(2) There are a bunch of matches.  Now, let's fetch the pages where `state_id` is located and compare to `Pni_QueryStateId`.  Ohh, that's a lot more work.

If that is the case, then having an index on `m_query(id, state_id)` should help the query.

By the way, this is assuming that the *only* change is in function call in the `where` clause.  If there are other changes to get fewer rows, you might just be calling this function fewer times.

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly the problem...thank you very much, I hadn't thought about the problem of an exclusion possibly taking longer.